# How to load url link to imageview properly and how to manage the image in cache?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, nsdate, nsurl

```
NSString *img=[arrImages objectAtIndex:i];
imgScrollView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:img]]];
```

I have displayed my code. The URL links have been stored into an array and the images are also fetching into uiimage view, but only the first two images are loaded into the imageview while the others didn't load .

```
arrImages:
```

inside image viewhttp://localhost:8888/welcome/company/0/images/TV Repair.png

this is the link present in the arrImages i don't know why first two images has been loading.

FOR LOOP:

```
    for(NSDictionary *DicHoleCategories in ArrCategory)
    {
        StrName=[DicHoleCategories objectForKey:@"image"];
        if(StrName!=nil)
        {
            subimages=[NSString stringWithFormat:LocalImage"%@",StrName];
            [DicAllValues setObject:subimages forKey:@"image"];
            NSError *error =nil;
        }
        [arrImages addObject:[DicAllValues objectForKey:@"image"]];
    }
```

Can anyone find the issue and help me please?

Comment: Plz post your for loop.

Comment: Any body help me whats wrong in my code......

Comment: None of the image url is not working.I checked these url in browser.It seems unable to connect.

Comment: its localhost url u will never get this except me @user3182143

Comment: guys help me still i cant get the answer.

Comment: at what format the nsdata has been convert the image view..

Answer (score 0):

please follow the below code

```
    if(StrName!=nil)
    {
        subimages=[NSString stringWithFormat:LocalImage"%@",StrName];
        [DicAllValues setObject:subimages forKey:@"image"];
        NSError *error =nil;
        [arrImages addObject:[DicAllValues objectForKey:@"image"]];//add here!

    }
```

Plz check now and tell me if its working or not!

Comment: but i get the 5 images url even though its not working

Comment: Copy paste the url in browser and check if those images are opening. Plz check and comment

Comment: Check for spaces before and after the url in the array!

Comment: but i get the link from imgArray via nslog,when i check the link it is working in my chrome browser[image has been loaded].

Answer (score 0):

Go through the below coding

```
 //url string 

 NSString *ImageURL = @"yoururl";

 //string to data conversion

  NSData *imagedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];

 //set image 

 imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: i have done this code also but only first two images has been loading in my image view